# A proper question got closed down

Tags: discussion, support

I posted a question with a lot of details

> [How do I prevent an exe and Powershell on Windows / PC to stop running altogether?](https://superuser.com/questions/1694892/how-do-i-prevent-an-exe-and-powershell-on-windows-pc-to-stop-running-altogethe)

But it got closed with the reason "not enough details provided".

One can argument "we do not know the reason for a crypto program", but the same principle goes with any `.exe`: when it crashes or stopped, the `pause` below it should prevent the `.bat` from finishing and would not cause the Powershell to disappear, so it is a perfectly valid Windows question.

Comment: Feel free to explain exactly what you mean by PowerShell disappearing. If something is causing the PowerShell instance to crash the script would not finish. Your question is far from having the details required to answer it

Comment: I explained what it means by Powershell disappearing. The window disappeared and the Window bar is not showing an instance is running. HOW DO I EXPLAIN why Powershell disappeared, you'd have to ask Microsoft. My question itself is, why would this happen. What may prevent it.  I could have used "loop" to go back to the first line of the `.bat` file so that if the `.exe` crashed, just repeat, but the `pause` should have shown that the `.exe` crashed, so the loop wouldn't help. I am asking a question with a lot of details, and you just closed it saying it doesn't have enough details.

Comment: You have failed to edit your question, clarifying your question with a comment, doesn’t make your question eligible to be reopened.

Comment: I edited my question numerous times. I will report your behavior directly to the headquarter of StackExchange @Ramhound

Comment: **I had absolutely no part in the closure of your question.**  You do understand that right?  Instead of providing edits that clarified what you meant by PowerShell disappearing, you made an edit, that suggested anyone that would close your question wasn't intelligent.  The only thing I have done is asked for you to clarify your question.

Comment: I made at least 4 edits. Maybe you don't see it. I am not sure why. But this world has enough accusations already

Comment: I saw the edits, I also saw information indicated in a comment, that wasn’t stated in the question body.